# consume webservice from running silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, ria

I've created a Silverlight Application with WCF Webservices (.svc) and RIA Domain Services from the SilverlightApplication.Web Project. The user has to enter user name and password for identification. The Web.config allows only authenticated users access to webservices.

I would like to write a Office Add-In which should consume some of these Webservices.

For the usage of my ria domain service, I have no idea....

For the .svc Services, I thought adding a Service Reference to my Office Add-In would be fine. Unfortunately, if it try to add a service reference to http://mydomain.com/ServiceTest.svc I'm getting a 404 error. Any ideas how I can authenticate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice tutorial:

www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/08/use-aspnet-membership-provider-with-a-wcf-svc-service/